# Build Maven project with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

How to build Maven with Gradle.

That is what `build.gradle` should be to use maven `pom.xml`

(Of course it will have some limitations or likely to new or external gradle plugin)

I have come on examples before, but cannot find in userguide.

Answer (score 3):

Have You read [Gradle guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) about Maven ? It depends on what You want to do with the `pom.xml` file. Another place to look is the [Gradle pom converter](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html#N14996) to fully convert your existing Maven build to Gradle.